# Generate table columns using m2doc

Tags: m2doc

I would like to know if it is possible to generate columns of a table using m2doc.

Currently, i am able to generate rows of a table by doing this:

```
{m:for r|rows} 
[] [] []
{m:endfor}
```

, where [][][] represents a static table with 3 columns.

On top of this i would like to add dynamically columns on the static table. So, i would assume that something like this could work:

```
{m:for r|rows} 
[] [] [] {m:for s|cells} *tableCell*{m:endfor}
{m:endfor}
```

However, i am not able to generate the cells horizontally, since that the expression  `{m:for s|cells} *tableCell*{m:endfor}` cannot be formatted in the same line in the word document. So, in the word document it appears as:

```
{m:for s|cells}                                    *tableCell*
   {m:endfor}
```

, which results to columns generated vertically.

Has anyone encountered the same problem? Is there a work around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [service](http://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/index.html#providing-new-services) that returns a [MTable](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/blob/master/plugins/org.obeonetwork.m2doc/src/org/obeonetwork/m2doc/element/MTable.java) and create the table programmatically. For the moment only text can be inserted in the cells of the [MTable](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/blob/master/plugins/org.obeonetwork.m2doc/src/org/obeonetwork/m2doc/element/MTable.java). You can have a look at the [sample table test](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/tree/master/tests/org.obeonetwork.m2doc.tests/resources/mTable/sample) and the service implementation is in the [MTableTestServices](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/blob/master/tests/org.obeonetwork.m2doc.tests/src/org/obeonetwork/m2doc/tests/services/MTableTestServices.java).